# How to get Access Code for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a image to google cloud storage from my AngularJS web app and to do the same i need the access code which is to be placed in Authorization header while requesting the upload. To get access token i had introduced an endpoint at server side which is developed in JAVA. My current code to get access token is like this

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new URL("HERE GOES URL OF MY SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON FILE").openStream());
if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
      credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
    }
String token = credential.getAccessToken();
log.log( Level.SEVERE, "5 "+token);
```

But in logs i am getting null.

Why i am getting the JSON file from a URL is because when i put the JSON file in same package it raised java.security.AccessControlException. So, to avoid that i placed the file on google drive and generated the direct download link which is used in above code.

I just want the access code and send it to web app so that upload can be initiated. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What are you trying to do with an access token directly? Most of the libraries that use GCS from App Engine take care of authorizing as the app engine service account automatically.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I am trying to upload a image to GCS using my web app built in angularJS and to achieve the same i have to send access token in authorization header.

Comment: Ah, so you are sending the access token to the client side, and then having the client use that token to perform an upload? If that's the case, I strongly suggest you use another approach, such as signed URLs, instead. The access token represents FULL rights to do anything the service account could do with that scope. A malicious client could, for instance, delete the bucket and all its contents.

Comment: Ohh .. Thank you @BrandonYarbrough for pointing out that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get credentials by using following class.

```
package XXXXXXXXXXXX;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;

//@author Umesh Chauhan 

public class StorageFactory
{

    private static Storage instance = null;

    public static synchronized Storage getService () throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {
        if ( instance == null )
        {
            instance = buildService ();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static Storage buildService () throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
    {

        HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport ();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory ();

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream (
                new URL ( "HERE GOES THE URL FOR YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT JSON - I USED GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECT DOWNLOAD LINK TO MY JSON FILE" )
                        .openStream () );

        // Depending on the environment that provides the default credentials
        // (for
        // example: Compute Engine, App Engine), the credentials may require us
        // to
        // specify the scopes we need explicitly. Check for this case, and
        // inject
        // the Cloud Storage scope if required.
        if ( credential.createScopedRequired () )
        {
            Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all ();
            credential = credential.createScoped ( scopes );
        }

        return new Storage.Builder ( transport, jsonFactory, credential ).setApplicationName ( "YOUR PROJECT NAME" ).build ();
    }
}
```

and further used that Storage object to Upload file to Google Cloud Storage.

If any one need complete answer on ["How to upload file to Google Cloud Storage ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38918931/3796784)

Comment: am not able to import these packages.. is there any libraries I need to add?                                                                                                               import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;

Comment: ok i added compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-storage', version: 'v1beta1-rev21-1.14.1-beta' in build.gradle and the import are working.

Comment: but now this all() method is not recognised... StorageScopes.all ();

Comment: I am using <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
       <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
       <version>v1-rev81-1.22.0</version>
     </dependency> in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using is not for App Engine instances. You can put JSON file with your app in the `/war/WEB_INF` folder like you would with any static file, but a better solution is to use code that works specifically on App Engine:

```
private static final AppIdentityService identityService = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();

String token = identityService
                .getAccessToken(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control")).getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei,
First of all thank you for your help but it is returning invalidToken. Complete token value is like this
"InvalidToken:https:// www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control:6058"

Comment: I use this code in my apps with no problems (FileMambo.com is one of them). Have you enabled the correct Cloud Storage API for your project?

Comment: In my google console i have these two APIs enabled
Google Cloud Storage, 
Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Comment: Is there anything else i am missing ?

Comment: One more thing i was able to get access code via this URL
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=none&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write